# setting noapic , nolapic and nomodeset at time of installation results in non-responsive keyboard

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, nomodeset

I need to install NVidia drivers on my new desktop. For this I was told that while installing Ubuntu I should cross the options "`noapic`", "`nolapic`" and "`nomodeset`" so that `nouveau` drivers are not installed.

I did that and after installation machine is not taking any input from keyboard at all. Also I can move mouse cursor on screen but left/right clicks are not working. I have tried installing 3 times with same procedure but with same result.

keyboard works properly at time of installation so keyboard is definitely not a problem.

So my questions are:
1. Is is correct to cross these options while installing Ubuntu if one wants to install NVidia drivers?
2. If answer to above question is YES, then what can be possible reason that mouse/keyboard not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were told wrong. If you are getting black screen issues, `nomodeset` is enough; `no(l)apic` are for more serious hardware issues, not just to install the Nvidia drivers. `noveau` running while you install the proprietary (binary/additional) drivers is also perfectly OK; it will be replaced seamlessly by them.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Initially I was installing Ubuntu 12.04 with procedure described in question and having problems of keyboard and mouse. Later I tried installing Ubuntu 11.04(before you answered this question) with same procedure and system is running now without any problems and I could install NVidia drives also. I am not sure whether it was issue with Ubuntu 12.04 or I was installing Ubuntu 12.04 with bad copy of CD.  I was waiting if any one has other solution which is consistent with experience. If I have any problems now I will definitely try your solution.